# Error llamando a función de Python desde C++

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

Quiero usar la biblioteca [xlwt](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/) en una aplicación hecha en Qt. Como es la primera vez que lo intento, estaba haciendo unas pruebas para ver cómo se hace la llamada, según esta página:

https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Creo un script en python, llamado `prueba.py`

> print "Hola mundo!"

Ahora lo quiero llamar desde una aplicación de C++:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* ruta = PyString_FromString("/home/usuario/programacion/prueba.py");
    PyObject* modulo = PyImport_Import(ruta);
    if( modulo)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Hay funcion";
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Pero se ve que '''modulo''' sigue a 0, no ocurre nada dentro de las llaves.
No sé que error tendré, pero ni siquiera puedo ponerme a probar alguna función con un script mas serio, porque ni puedo cargar el módulo.

**Edito:**

De esta forma si funciona (la pongo como solución):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *scriptDirectoryName = "/home/usuario/programacion/";
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("prueba.py");
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente para saber que excepción lanza el script:
`if (module == nullptr) {
    PyErr_Print();
}`

Comment: @meegle84, gracias por el consejo, el error es esclarecedor: "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported." Aún así no sé cual es la causa ni cómo arreglarlo

Comment: Comprueba que tienes permisos de ejecución en `prueba.py`

Comment: @meegle84, le doy permisos de ejecución pero sigo igual. No obstante tirando del hilo me encuentro con una forma de cargar los módulos diferente. El caso es que la forma que intenté es la forma "oficial" pero....tampoco tengo mucha idea de todo esto, y tendré que verlo en detalle (de python voy muy justo)

Comment: Si ya has encontrado una solución te sugeriría publicar una respuesta y marcar la misma como solución. Así tu pregunta será de ayuda para otros que se encuentren con el mismo problema (si no tiene respuestas y no está marcada como solucionada será menos reconocible)

Comment: @eferion, no lo puse como solución porque no es realmente una respuesta a mi pregunta, sino una forma alternativa de hacer lo que quiero hacer. Además no me resuelve la duda de por qué no me funciona mi código. Además de encontrar una solución que funcione me gusta saber por qué no me ha funcionado la otra. No obstante como parece que esta pregunta no va a tener más recorrido y por si a alguien le puede servir la respuesta, la pondré como solución. Gracias ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finalmente una forma de llamar a un script de Python puede ser esta:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *scriptDirectoryName = "/home/usuario/programacion/";
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("prueba.py");
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```